# Apply XSLT to add a tag

Tags: xml, xslt, tags, xslt-2.0, adobe-indesign

I'm exporting an XML file from InDesign. The text in this file contains superscripts referring to a specific grammatical concept; however, these superscripts are exported as text in the XML file. I need to write an XSLT so that when it's applied to the InDesign file it will simply add a little tag to the superscript.

This is how it's exported:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
<Content>
<PhraseNative aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="260.5">
<Phrase>    1.  Mark is1a playing2 videogames.</Phrase> 
</PhraseNative>
</Content>
</Root>
```

This should be the final code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
<Content>
<PhraseNative aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="260.5">
<Phrase>    1.  Mark is<tag>1a</tag> playing<tag>2</tag> videogames.</Phrase> 
</PhraseNative>
</Content>
</Root>
```

These tags would always appear whenever a number and a letter are the two or three last digits of a string. Sometimes it will be only a number. The output doesn't change at all. This is just so the tags are not lost when exported back into a web page.

Comment: You retagged this to xslt1, but is there any reason you can't use xslt2 (thus is _much_ easier with xslt 2)

Comment: InDesign doesn't support 2.0 However, I then figured out that I can just apply it through another software. It's been retagged as XSLT 2.0.

Comment: OK, well then @DevNull's answer seems fine:-)

Comment: Yes! You're right. I just have a last question though. Do you know how it would be so it tags just the number that comes after a word? I tried changing the regex around so that it would do that, but it ends up tagging every number in the code. If you could help me out with that I would be sooo glad!

Comment: @babyeumbrella - I've updated my answer. Hopefully this will do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged the question with XSLT 2.0, so here's a 2.0 option.

Note: I had to add a dummy xmlns for the `aid` prefix.

Also, you'll most likely need to refine the regex, but this should get you started.

**XML Input**

```
<Root>
  <Content>
    <PhraseNative aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="260.5" xmlns:aid="somexmlns">
      <Phrase>    1.  Mark is1a playing2 videogames.</Phrase> 
    </PhraseNative>
  </Content>
</Root>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:aid="somexmlns">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Phrase">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([a-z]+)([0-9]+[a-z]*)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
          <tag>
            <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>    
          </tag>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Root>
   <Content>
      <PhraseNative xmlns:aid="somexmlns" aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1"
                    aid:ccolwidth="260.5">
         <Phrase>    1.  Mark is<tag>1a</tag> playing<tag>2</tag> videogames.</Phrase>
      </PhraseNative>
   </Content>
</Root>
```

*Tested using Saxon-HE 9.3.*

Comment: If you ever have time, and would like to explain to me how this works,  I would be eternally grateful. I find this XSLT option to be great to work with InDesign, so if I can understand what it's doing maybe in the future I won't have to bother you again :)